# How to show object in array angular?

Tags: arrays, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to show comments in items?

This is where items save

```
$scope.items = [
{ 'item': 'one',
'comments':[{'comment':'comment'}]
},
{ 'item': 'two',},
{'item': 'three'}
];


<ul>
<li ng-repeat="ite in items">
{{ite.item}} {{ite.comments.length}}
<button ng    click="remove($index)">Remove</button> <div ng-repeat="c in ite.comments">{{c.comment}}</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/19w1Q3XhoWQcpxm5SuxX?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You Just missed to add your comment Div in between the list tag. please update the code like above code. I have checked on Plunker.

```
<li ng-repeat="ite in items">
{{ite.item}} {{ite.comments.length}}
<button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button> <div ng-repeat="c in ite.comments">{{c.comment}}</div></li>
```